# 2007 Honda CRV electrical problems

Tags: honda, electrical, lights, crv

I have a 2007 Honda CR-V I had some DRL fitted about a year ago and they’ve been fine until very recently they began to flicker at times.

I decided to investigate and I must have hit a wire or something as there was a slight click noise and all the lights went off. Now I don’t have any side lights at all or DRL. The brake lights, head lights, fog lights, main beam, indicators, and reverse lights work, but no side lights front or rear.

I’ve checked all bulbs and fuses which are all fine. Can anyone help as I need my car for work and I don’t want to drive it at night without any rear lights?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ricky.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of cases where aftermarket electrical connections are not made with longevity in mind. Therefore, over time they come apart, get corroded or simply lose connectivity.

From what you described, it sounds as though a connection has come undone, or a wire has been broken, thereby opening the circuit which causes those lights not to work. The add-on DRL may have been spliced into the wiring for the side markers, so follow the wires from the DRL to where they connect to see if there is a problem there.

If you find out more details, please update your question with what you find so we can give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Okay I’ve just followed the DRL to where they’re wired

Comment: Okay I’ve just followed the DRL to where they’re wired, you are right the side lights have been spliced. I’ve removed the DRL and covered the spliced wires with electrical tape but they’re still not working, I’ve checked the bulbs and fuses again and still nothing. Is there a reset I need to do or a different fuse I need to check

Comment: Sorry I should also add that I have removed the DRL completely and am now trying to find why my factory fitted side lights front and rear are still not working

Comment: It is possible during the splicing process they cut through the wires they spliced into. Double check the wires at the previously spliced area. Then find the ground and verify it is soundly attached. Lastly, verify the fuses again for that circuit.

Comment: Okay I’ve just double checked the spliced wires, both negative and positive are intact and undamaged. also double checked connections before and after the splice and they look fine. also double checked the fuses, but still nothing. What would happen if the positive and negative wires touched, it’s just a theory but when I removed the DRL the spliced connection looked very worn and electrical tape wasn’t in amazing condiction, could me “investigating” have caused the spliced wires to touch and maybe trip the circuit

Comment: If the wires had shorted, it should have blown the fuse. It might be worth checking the fuse with a multimeter for continuity. If you don't have a multimeter, you can swap the fuse with a known good one of the same amperage. If that doesn't reveal anything, you will need to start checking for power at various points in the circuit to find where the problem is. Wires can look fine on the outside and be damaged on the inside if they get pinched or crimped in any way. Not much more we can help you with.